# Mysql select all users except users with @example1.com and @example2.com mails

Tags: php, mysql

I have an email addresses like user@example1.com , user@example2.com  and user@example3.com . I want select query so that it would exclude all users using example1, example2 & example3.com domains and showing all other users using mails like user@blabla.com.

**Edit:** I used

```
select * from users where mailaddress  
  NOT like '%banned_domain1.com%'  
    or NOT like '%banned_domain2.com%'  
      or NOT like '%banned_domain3.com%' ;
```

but doesn't work

Comment: Excellent request. Show what you've done to attempt to achieve this.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tableemails WHERE email NOT LIKE '%@example%'` but I need the query to combine all the example1,example2 and example3.com domains and I used or but it shows errors `SELECT * FROM tableemails WHERE email NOT LIKE '%@example%' or '%example2.com`

Comment: @Mtaly What about `user@example-anywhere.com` and `user@example.org` Do you want to include them in your result or exclude them?

Comment: I want to Exclude banned domains I used this query but I got syntax error : `select * from users where mailaddress NOT like '%banned_domain1.com%' or NOT like '%banned_domain2.com%' or NOT like '%banned_domain3.com%' ;`

Comment: You got a syntax error, being what? You need to show us exactly how you're trying to use that query. Via phpmyadmin? via PHP? other?

Comment: MySQL command line for now

Comment: As per your edit: No need to edit your question with what worked. Accepting an answer is enough. I did a rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to exclude multiple domains that  are not name similarly then do this -

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table`
WHERE `email` NOT LIKE '%foo%'
AND `email` NOT LIKE '%bar%'
AND `email` NOT LIKE '%baz%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tableemails WHERE email NOT LIKE '%@example%'
```

Comment: It works for single domain but I need the query to exclude multiple domains at one time

Comment: when you put '%%' at the two sides, it compares with everything that contains these string in this case, it will exclude all the strings that contains the '@example' string